Can I use PVC to tie into sewer drain with 3 elbows and 10 foot run?
The house we are in currently has a flexible discharge tube from water softener to nearby floor drain which goes to sump pit. To avoid burnout and sump pump getting rusty I’d like to tie the discharge line into our sewer drain line.
To make for a clean run I would have to have three 90 degree elbows and a 10 ft run to tie into vertical sewer drain. I plan to put a P-trap and air gap device if I tie in directly.  Is this run acceptable (with three elbows and 10 ft of straight run) and is pvc ok to use for the discharge drain line?  I want to use PVC for cleaner look and concerns about being sturdy enough as discharge is under pressure.

PVC (assuming Schedule 40) is rated to at least 120 PSI. You'll never come within a universe of exceeding that in an open circuit.

I read that some municipalities do not allow water softener discharge into the sewer system.

You will need an "air gap" at the point where the water softener drain connects to the sewer drain system. Goes on the upstream (softener, input) side of the trap.
This prevents any potential siphoning of sewage into the potable water system from a malfunction.
The DWV portion of the PVC (or ABS if your sewer line happens to be ABS) would be from the sewer connection to the trap, and would follow drainage system rules (minimum slope and diameter and venting requirements.) It is common to have a "standpipe" on the input to the trap so that it does not overflow if the drainage is fast. You'll see them on most washing machine drain inlets.
The "pressurized output" portion of the system would begin on the other side of the air gap and can use pipe sizes unacceptable for drain pipes, ignore slope, etc. If the PVC pipe is not smaller than the usual tubing employed, 10 feet and 3 elbows should not be a problem.
The air gap itself can be accomplished with a fitting made for the purpose, or by a literal gap between the lower end of the pressurized pipe and the upper end of the trap inlet drain pipe, which is at least 2 pipe diameters (of the pressurized pipe.) The fittings are simply a prefabricated way to attain the required gap.
